# Set Combobox Items and DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm having a problem where every time I build my solution, the compile succeeds but when I run my program it will error as the forms designer.cs file has had the data source for my custom comboboxes added to it automatically; resulting in an exception stating

> Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.

Any ideas on what might be the problem? I've tried setting the data source after the initialize component method but this results in a different error as the unit type is null..

The type of data source is set in a property for the control and below is the relevant code

*form.Designer.cs (this is generated for you not a custom cs file called designer)*

```
// 
// cmbWheelUnitCR
// 
this.cmbWheelUnitCR.DataSource = ((object)(resources.GetObject("cmbWheelUnitCR.DataSource")));
this.cmbWheelUnitCR.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
this.cmbWheelUnitCR.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.cmbWheelUnitCR.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
"mm",
"yd"});
```

*My custom combobox*

```
public string UnitType
{
   get { return m_unitType; }
   set { m_unitType = value;
   this.DataSource = Units.Instance.UnitTypes(m_unitType);}
}
public UnitComboBox()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: The exception message says that you cannot do `cmbWheelUnitCR.Items.AddRange(...)` if you do `cmbWheelUnitCR.DataSource = ...`. Have you tried removing the DataSource?

Comment: Everything is clear. You can't change Items collection because DataSource is set.

Comment: I don't want to change the items, I want to set them once and only once (done when unit type is set currently as shown) If i delete the lines out of the designer.cs file then it will run fine until the next time I make changes to the dialog

Comment: why not combine the data source and the manual collection earlier on and bind that result?

Comment: @Wimbo - I'm quite happy to bind the data to the source as early as possible, I thought I was doing it at the earliest possible point?

Comment: He's saying you should add your "mm", "yd" to the `resources.GetObject("cmbWheelUnitCR.DataSource")` collection and then use the result for your `ComboBox` datasource. You can't combine manually added items ("mm", "yd") and bindings.

Comment: the form.designer.cs is generated for you, I'd prefer if Visual studio left me to decide my own data source :) I can't add "mm" and "yd" to it as they're in a list populated from an instance variable (dictionary) that has a fundamental use. I can delete the lines out of the designer.cs files myself but its tedious every time i want to update something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this accidentally by setting the data source within an override onLoad event..